# Javascript method styles : What is the difference between these two method styles?

Tags: javascript, methods

What is the difference between these two method styles in Javascript? Is it just an optical difference or are there more subtle differences?

```
Ticket.createDetailView = function(elem) {..}

Ticket = {
   createDetailView: function(elem) {..}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first version stores the function in a new property without replacing the object in `Ticket` while the second one creates a *new* object containing only one property: `createDetailView`

However assuming the object was empty in the first case there is no real difference. For example, the following two code snippets are pretty much equivalent:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = 123;
foo.baz = 456;
```

and

```
var foo = {
    bar: 123,
    baz: 456
}
```